# Install app without asking user

Tags: android, permissions, installation

My application will be running on hundreds of android devices belonging to a single owner and I may need to modify the software as an update at some point.

I decided I should include a feature to check with the server for updates and download them, which is currently working.

Installing the update is the difficult part. I need it done automatically. Preferably with no user interaction since there are hundreds of devices and it would be very time consuming to do each one manually.

This is the problem, even with the device rooted, I can not find a generic way that each device can install the update without system specific information.

I have read questions like this but can not find a proper answer: [Install Android APK without prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26926274/install-android-apk-without-prompt)

The bottom answer executes but I can find no installed app, so I assume it failed.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is not possible without some serious hacks. A **private app store** might be a better fit.

If your client is a **Google Apps** user, you can create a private channel in the Play Store.
[Distribute Android apps in your organization](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en)

If not, you will have to rely on third party solution like these one:

- [Apperian Mobile Application Management](https://www.apperian.com/mobile-application-management/)
- [ManageEngine Mobile Device Manager](https://www.manageengine.com/mobile-device-management)

I didn't try any of these, so you will have to do some research to check that they fit your needs