# Install new apk after download by Download Manager and exit from running app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver, android-download-manager

I have create android app using java. But i want upgrade my app without playstore.
I try to download manually but it make more time to do that.
I want make it simply.
So i use download manager for download new file from my server.
And now i donno how to install automatically my new app.

What shoul i do ?

This is manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="28"/>

<application
        ...
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        ...
</application>
```

And this what i have tried for download file :

```
String destination = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/";
destination += name_app_list;

final Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + destination);

final DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse("url" + name_app_list));
request.setDestinationUri(uri);
request.setMimeType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

final DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
final long downloadID = manager.enqueue(request);
```

And this i have tried to install that apk :

```
BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
   public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
      Intent intez = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
      intez.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(name_app_list)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
      startActivity(intez);
   }
};

registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
```

This Error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dsi.updateapp/com.dsi.updateapp.MainActivity}: android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/1.4/phd.apk exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/1.4/phd.apk exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()
        at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1799)
        at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2346)
        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:8933)
        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:8894)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1517)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4224)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:597)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4183)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:583)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4507)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4475)
        at com.dsi.updateapp.MainActivity.openFile(MainActivity.java:202)
        at com.dsi.updateapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:109)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Install android app programatically without prompt,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50462853/how-to-install-android-app-programatically-without-prompt)

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, I'll try it first

Comment: not work, it just redownload what have i do

Comment: You have not described which problems you have with your code. We dont know what happens.

Comment: omg, sorry... I want to install new app using my running app. Now i got error receiving broadcast Intent. im not sure thats can be work, so i want to ask how to install new app from download manager in running app then close that running app and open new app.

Comment: `Now i got error receiving broadcast Intent` Again you did not tell the problem. Which error? And as long as you cannot download you should not even talk about installing. We conclude that the file is not even downloaded?

Comment: download success, i want install automatically after download that file

Comment: We know that by long. But where exactly does it go wrong? Come to the point please. And you still did not tell that error.

Comment: I've updated the post for the error display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I search all day, i got the solution
Thank you for comment my post :)
**This is my solution**
Add to manifest :

```
<provider
   android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
   android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
   android:exported="false"
   android:grantUriPermissions="true">
   <meta-data 
      android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
      android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>

</provider>
```

add new dir and file xml/provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="downloads" path="."/>
</paths>
```

And then in Activity :

```
BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
   public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
      Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", destination);
      Intent intents = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
      intents.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      intents.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
      intents.setDataAndType(uri,"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
      startActivity(intents);
   }
};

registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
```